# How can I place a dot after each character using preg replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace

The purpose of this code is to find independent characters and place a dot after each character. eg. "Jane Doe L D I" should return "Jane Doe L. D. I."

My code works under certain conditions. However, when I use the following scenarios it fails. It fails when I use a string of "Jeans Shirts K/N" and returns "Jeans Shirts K./N."

```
$string = "Jeans Shirts K-92";  
echo preg_replace('/\b[A-z]{1}\b/', '$0.', $string);   

Result: (Fail)   
Jeans Shirts K.-92

Expected Result:
Jeans Shirts K-92
```

Comment: Maybe you need [`\b[A-Za-z](?=\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/sQ1kJ6/1)?

Comment: Or maybe [`(?<=\s|^)[A-Za-z](?=\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/sQ1kJ6/2)? Please specify the requirements, examples are not going to help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<=\s|^)[A-Za-z](?=\s|$)/', '$0.', $string);
//=> Jeans Shirts K-92
```

`[A-z]` is incorrect as it matches many more character between ASCII `A` (65) and `z` (122).

Comment: Thanks. your response of echo preg_replace('/\b[A-Z]\b(?!\.)/', '$0.', $string);  solves only one part. What about K/N scenarios?

Comment: What is expected result for `Jeans Shirts K/N`?

Comment: It should not be modified and return the same Jeans Shirts K/N However your code still returns Jeans Shirts K./N.

Comment: Oh yes, that is my suggestion.

Comment: @user2635901: In case that doesn't work I strongly suggest you to edit the question and clarify the requirements. Information via comments does not make it a useful question.